# Photoshop adding border on saving to a JPG image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, jpg, error

I don't know why but, when I save a Photoshop file it automatically changes the file size and adds a white padding on the top and bottom of the image: see a screen recording how this is happening here:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your artboard is smaller than your canvas. *Save, Save As,* and *Save for Web* saves the entire canvas not merely the artboard you are working on.

Use `File > Export > Export As...` rather than *Save* or *Save For Web* if you need to save artboards and not the entire canvas. *Save, Save As,* and *Save For Web* don’t recognize (acknowledge) artboard sizes.

Comment: @Scott see [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43678588#43678588)

Comment: @WELZ I agree they shouldn't ever be a substitute for bold/italics. That's *not* how I use them. I use them for *menu trees* which is not "emphasis". It's more about separation than emphasis since that block of text is a tree and not meant to be broken. It should be seen as a single item, like code.

Comment: I would much rather use them, it may require a new Meta post.

Comment: Honestly :) It's not like I'm unaware of how to use bold and italics :) It is really stylistic, I prefer trees to be seen as a whole if possible and I always use angled brackets rather than arrows. I can see how using the back ticks for italics or bold makes reading terrible, but I think it's actually *better* for tree structures.

Comment: @Scott: If you really want something not to be broken, use protected spaces. Abusing backticks substitutes a minor issue (or a non issue if you ask me, why shouldn’t these be broken?) with a bigger one. Anyway, if you really want to contest this, please take it to [meta].

Answer (score 0):

Try making a copy of the file and flatten the layers.

There are probably some objects outside the canvas.